# How to display the amount of users currently connected to a discord server in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ive got alot of features working on my bot, but im stuck on something that should seem so simple but I can't seem to figure it out, I want to be able to type a command with my prefix that will then display the amount of users currently on the discord.

I've got an if statment that activates the command

```
if (msg.content == prefix + 'users') {
}
```

So i've got the activator but ive searched several other posts of how to simply get the guild and count the users but none are very straight forward. Ive tried several solutions and all crash the bot or print mass error reports.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'd use `guild.memberCount`.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount

Comment: How would I implement that tho, and how would I get the guild, would I create a new constant with the server Id or would I simply just put in `memberscount = client.guild.memberCount;`

then print `msg.channel.send (memberscount);`

Comment: `Guild` is available through the `Message`. So something like `msg.guild.memberCount` so you don't need to worry about IDs. :) 

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild

Comment: so my code would have to look something like this ?

`if (msg.content == prefix + 'users') { msg.guild.memberCount;}`

Comment: Kinda, you'd need to send the message to the channel though, right?

`msg.channel.send ( msg.guild.memberCount );`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, I love how ive managed to get a music bot working with youtube links yet something this simple got me stumped.